# Split column in list by row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I had a pandas dataframe in which the column 'Product ID' is a series.
I need to transform this column in lists by rows

```
ID_Pedido   ID_Produto
0          1  AC1,CD2,UE4
1          2  AC1,OP3,KJ7
2          3      CD2,UE4

type(df['ID_Produto'])
pandas.core.series.Series


Desired result:

 ID_Pedido   ID_Produto
0          1  ['AC1','CD2','UE4']
1          2  ['AC1','OP3','KJ7']
2          3  ['CD2','UE4']
```

Comment: Cool! Do you mean that you tried to do it but it didn't work?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings

Comment: `df['ID_Produto'] = df['ID_Produto'].apply(lambda x: list(x.split(',')))`.

Comment: It worked applying:

df['ID_Produto'] = df['ID_Produto'].apply(lambda x: list(x.split(',')))

and in this way

df2 = df['ID_Produto'].str.split(",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert column *`Product ID`* values into a list, you can update the column by splitting the values at each comma, `split()` will return a list as desired:

```
df['ID_Produto'] = df['ID_Produto'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

This differs slightly from @Tim Roberts's approach as it did not explicitly convert the split values into a list using `list()`, as the splited values are already returned as a list, both return similar result.